# how to use" $ ln -sf ../models" in windows command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, command-line-interface

i am trying to use

**$ ln -sf ../models** but its giving me error :

**'ln' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Not sure how to use this command on windows

So baiscally i am following the intstruction in "full stack webdevelopment in backbone"..

i want to execute :

```
$ mkdir -p app/models
$ mkdir -p app/node_modules

$ cd app/node_modules
$ ln -sf ../models 
$ cd app
$ node

> Movie = require('models/movie');
> movie = new Movie({title: "The Artist"})
```

and output should be :

```
> movie = new Movie({title: "The Artist"})
{ cid: 'c1',
attributes:
{ title: 'The Artist',
year: 0,
description: 'empty',
selected: false },
_changing: false,
_previousAttributes: {},
changed: {},
_pending: false }
```

My folder **app/models/movie.js**

moive.js contain :

```
var Backbone = require("Backbone");
var Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
title: "default",
year: 0,
description: "empty",
selected: false
}
});
module.exports = Movie;
```

Comment: it's a "unix" command, so can not be used in windows

Comment: so is there any replacement of this command? how can i execute this on windows

Comment: for windows vista/2008 and newer - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: [You can create symlinks in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) but that doesn't mean that doing so is a good idea. Maybe explain the context in which you need this?

Comment: so basically i want to execute this command  : 
 Movie = require('models\movie')  but i am missing that "Ln" command and due to this.. my Movie command is getting fail

Comment: so, the node module assumes **ln** is a command, therefore assumes it's on a **unix/posix** operating system, so, you're probably going to have far more issues than the lack of **ln** command. Perhaps contact the creator of that module and ask them if it will run in windows